# Firebase Cloud Function Warning (Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I just set up a cloud function triggered by a sub/pub topic. The function triggers an HTTP-triggered cloud function by, well, making a GET request. It all works well, the only thing that doesn't quite line up is a warning message

```
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
```

I have to admit I'm not as fluent in promises as I should be, and that might be the reason for the error. Here is the Node code.

```
exports.triggerClearHidden = functions.runWith(global.runtimeOptions).pubsub.topic('trig').onPublish((message) => {
        // const pubsubMessage = message.data;
        // console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, 'base64').toString());
        let urlstr = functions.config().rain.projecturl + "/clearHidden";
        httpGetAsync(urlstr, (txt => console.log(txt)));
});


function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xmlHttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200){
            return callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
        } else {
            return callback("the ready state is " + xmlHttp.readyState + " and the status is " + xmlHttp.status);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: try `return httpGetAsync(urlstr, (txt => console.log(txt)));` otherwise, you function will return unfined as it is rn

Comment: Your pubsub function needs to return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.  That's how Cloud Functions knows your function is ready to tear down.  Right now you are returning nothing.

Comment: @andresmijares That won't work because httpGetAsync doesn't itself also return a promise when the request is complete.

Comment: Ok, so pubSub can create and return a Promise using 'new Promise(function(resolve,reject){httpGetAsync...}). Should the httpGetAsync function use the same promise (and if so, how?). Or should it create a new promise to pass into 'callback' (in which case callback could resolve it)?